# Python: Why is this import failing with a FileNotFoundError despite other files in the same folder importing correctly?

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis

I'm currently dealing with a strange bug when running a Python script from SSIS/a SQL Server Agent Job after promoting to a production server. This issue didn't arise in dev/staging environments, only when promoting to production. When importing several other files from the same folder the main script is located in, no error is raised, but on the final import I'm getting an error of the form 'FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')' ; the relevant portions of the script looks something like this:

(The issues arise before loading the config file for the application which parameterizes the logging location, hence the ugly fallback logging here)

```
#!Python3.8
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(site-packages path)

from xyz import obj1, obj2
from abc import obj3
etc.

# Additional try/except block to figure out specific error for this import
try:
    import script_in_question
except Exception as e:
    with open(fallback log path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(f"{sys.argv}")
        f.write(f"Could not load script_in_question: {repr(e)} \n {os.getcwd()}")
        f.write(f"\n {repr(e)}")
```

Weirdly, when logging sys.path, I can see the folder containing the successfully imported scripts and the script in question; os.getcwd() reports the correct working directory, and this error cropped up whether I was directly importing the script or using noation like 'from script_in_question import main_function'

I've tried switching between from script_in_question import main_function and import script_in_question, explicitly changing to the correct working directory.

Comment: Could you perhaps post `script_in_question.py` ? And/or (preferrably and) could you run it without the `try/except`, or with a `raise` at the end of the except, and post the full stack trace here?

Comment: Definitely- let me take a second to get that ready, dealing with work code so I'm erring on the side of caution about posting the details- will post a follow-up with the requested info.

Comment: Wound up figuring out my issue here- turns out that there was a logging issue raising a filenotfound error in script_in_question.py that was making the failed import seem like it was unable to find the file- thanks for helping me figure out my silly mistake here! Happy to accept an answer if you'd like to submit this question as one and I can add the additional details in the comments therein.

Comment: did you actually do anything to change things and effect a fix? in that case, _you_ should post the answer, and we can comment there for context :)

If it's something where you just sort of figured out what was happening, but didn't do anything to change behaviour, I'll do that